# excel hyperlink using cell content but only the first 6 characters

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I want to create a hyperlink in column b but used the first 8 characters from column a. This is what it looks like:

```
Column A       
G1003700.CHG
```

I want the hyperlink to be `C:\JE Project\G1003700.pdf`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("C:\JE Project\";LEFT(A1;8);".pdf"))
```

This takes the first eight characters from the cell `A1` and makes a hyperlink after adding `C:\JE Project\`at the front, and `.pdf`at the end.

Comment: When I used your suggestion, I get this error message:     We found a problem with this formula. Try clicking Insert Function on the Formulas tab to fix it, or click Help for more info on common formula problems.

Comment: @user3242868 That's odd, did you copy and paste it in from here? And what version of Excel are you using? I tried this successfully with Excel 2010.

Comment: Yes, I copied and paste it. I have Excel 2013.

Comment: @user3242868 Then I can't tell you why it won't work as I don't have access to Excel 2013. I did try it in Excel Online, and that worked too. One thing that could be an issue is that Excel uses translated names for functions so if your language isn't English, then the names of the functions will be different (translated to your language).